# SM30 error Changes to repository or cross-client customizing are not permitted

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

I created a table in SAP via se11, then I used the table maintenance generator. Then I transported the changes from development system to q-system.

Now I want to maintain the table via sm30. This works in the DEV system. I just get a warning: "This table is cross-client". But editing works. In the QA system it does not work. I get:

> Changes to repository or cross-client customizing are not permitted

How to make a cross-client table editable?

The table's delivery class is `C`. The table's data class is `APPL2`. No there is no column MANDT (on purpose).

I know that I can edit this table with `&SAP_EDIT` in se16n, but I would like to avoid this dirty hack.

Comment: What is the table data class (under "Technical settings")?
Does the table have MANDT field as first key?
What option was checked for "record routine" while generating the table maintenance?

Comment: This is based on client setting (see transaction SCC4 and/or table T000, talk to Basis guys, if necessary). On the other hand, this is normal behaviour as table maintenance are for dev system (by default), after that entries are imported into test and prod systems. If your intention was to create a customizing table, which you can maintain directly in all systems, than by generating the table maintenance you have to select the option "no, or user recoding routine" (by Recording Routine)

Comment: @Dorad The table's delivery class is C. The table's data class is APPL2. No there is no column MANDT (on purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make cross-client editing via sm30 possible:

Use "table maintenance generator" (via se11). Then option "recording routine", there you need to set "no, or user recording routine".

[image: no, or user recording routine]

Then you are able to edit tables via sm30 which are cross-client tables (without column MANDT).

Answer (score 2):

This is not allowed because the setting for Cross-Client Object Changes is set for this client in such a way.

Go to `SCC4` select your client and change the following setting if you can and are allowed to.

[image: SCC4: Cross-Client Object Changes]

Comment: Usually, in one system, there's one client allowing cross-client customizing, and one or more clients which don't allow it. This is for security purpose, because any cross-client customizing might have undesirable effects on **ALL** clients of the system. People log in this reserved client only for this reason (or other special reasons). So, ask your administrator what is the client reserved to cross-client customizing (or look directly in SCC4).

Comment: @SandraRossi I am not allowed to start SCC4. Is there an other way to see the client which is allowed to edit cross-client tables. Then the question is solved. I could logon into this client and always change the values in this client.

Comment: SCC4 leaves my area of responsibility. This would be a basic change. I would like to solve this answer without changing global settings.

Comment: @guettli Table T000, column CCNOCLIIND (possible values shown in the value help). Why do you need a cross-client table? (or why don't you make it a client-dependent table? i.e. by adding first key column using the `CLNT` predefined type)